# How to use re.compile in Python if I want to match alphabetic word only

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm learning the RE module for Python and doing some experiment.  I have question regarding using expression, here is the example:

```
name = 'abc123def456'
m = re.compile('.*[^0-9]').match(name)
m.group()
print m
```

Result is 'abc123def'

What should I do if I want to totally take out the numeric number

Thank you!

Comment: `\D`: a non-digit character. Your regex would be `\D+`

Comment: By having the * you are matching the first set of numeric as well because there are non numeric after that. You could use '[^0-9]' as well

Comment: There are 2 sequences of digits in the string. Which one do you need to get? Both?

Comment: Well, `re.findall(r'[0-9]+', name)` should fetch you these sequences. `re.search(r'[0-9]+', name).group()` will fetch the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract all occurrences of alphabets and concatenate them to get just the alphabets in the string. See below:

```
"".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",name))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need.  Thank you!